# Create Query to See any Changeset that is not related to any TFS Ticket

Tags: tfs, changeset

I am working with a big team and we require each developer must associate their changeset with a specific ticket. Is their a way to create a query or report to Identify these problems.

Comment: What's the **TFS Ticket**? Are you using some extension? or just meaning the work item?

Comment: yes I mean work item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are meaning the work item. There is no simple query can achieve your requirement. You may need to use **TFS API**. Usually the simplest way is listing all the changeset with that specific ticket(work item)

How to use TFS API to list the changeset with a work item, you can refer this blog: [Listing the work items associated with changesets for a path](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/02/01/listing-the-work-items-associated-with-changesets-for-a-path/)